# Retofit create request inside object

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to get data from: https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json

Here is my code:

```
public class ApiClient {


    private final static String DOMAIN = "https://yts.lt/api";
    private final static String API = "/v2/list_movies.json/";

    private final static String BASE_URL = String.format("%s%s", DOMAIN, API);


    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    //Retrofit
    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}


public interface ApiService {

    //how to create the GET?

    @GET("all")
     Single<List<Movie>> getAllMovies();
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ApiService apiService;
    private CompositeDisposable mDisposable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        apiService = ApiClient.getInstance().create(ApiService.class);


        mDisposable.add(apiService.getAllMovies().
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Movie>>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final List<Movie> movies) {


                        Log.d(TAG,"Sucess");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, String.format("onError: %s", e.getMessage()), e);

                    }
                })
        );
    }
}
```

Movie:

```
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;


    public String getNameTitle() {
        return title;
    }


}
```

Error:

```
E/DTAG: onError: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

The movies array is located in object►data►movies►
And I need to get it? can you please help me how to create the @GET

Comment: just parse what you need ignore the other fields

Comment: Post your `Movie.java` too.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini - Ok

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher, Yes... thats is what I wish to do, but the array of movies is inside the object, and I need to get to movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint return type is not well structured. It should have the same structure as the endpoint response. You should create the following classes:

```
class MoviesResponse {
   @SerializedName("data")
   MoviesData data;
   ...
}

class MoviesData {
   @SerializedName("movies")
   List<Movie> data;
   ...
}

class Movie {
   @SerializedName("title")
   String title;
   ...
}
```

*Note that you should add the properties you want in each class, for example, in `MoviesResponse` you could also add `status` field as it is in the JSON response.*

Then change your service to have as return type the `MoviesResponse`

```
public interface ApiService {

     @GET("all")
     Single<MoviesResponse> getAllMovies();
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the @SerializedName annotation if the field is called the same. This is just for when the model coming from json doesn't match the Java field. (e.g.: the `MoviesData` class used it correctly, although I would have just called it `List<Movie> movies` instead).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I just wanted to follow the same structure he's using. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think you need to search a little bit how to parse JSON using GSON.

There are plenty of good answers here on StackOverflow.

You will need to either selectively parse what you want and construct your `Movie` objects while iterating the Array, or create all the model objects that represent the above structure given by your JSON and let GSON parse the whole tree of objects for you.

What you cannot do, is neither of the above.

By "quickly" looking at your JSON (I mean that sarcastically because it's huge...), I can see its structure is somehow like this:

Classes are `()`, fields are `lower_case`

```
ResponseRoot()
  status,
  status_message
  Data()
     limit,
     movie_count, 
     etc.,
     MoviesList() 
          Movie()
              id, url, etc..
              Genres() //this is a List<String> from what I see
              Torrents() // list<Torrent>
              date_uploaded,
              date_uploaded_unix
          Movie()
          Movie()
          Movie()
          ...
```

Kinda like that. So when a thing is a JSON array, the equivalent in java is a List.

And `ofThatThing` is the Class you have to provide with the fields.

E.g.:

the above "pseudo-class" for Movie would look: (simplified, I didn't copy all the fields)

```
class Movie {
   int id;
   String url;
   String imdb_code;
   ...
   List<String> genres;
   String summary;
   List<Torrent> torrents;
}
```

You'd need to have Torrent object so...

```
class Torrent {
   String url;
   String hash;
   String quality;
   etc..
}
```

You get the idea.